# Why are my routes not behaving as expected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have 3 actions in a controller. I would like the first two to be `/posts/new`, and the last to be `/posts/{filter}?page=N`

```
//all are in the PostsController
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult New()

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(PostView post)

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Browse(string filter, int page)
```

The routes I have defined now are:

```
routes.MapRoute("BrowsePosts",
    "posts/{filter}",
    new { controller = "posts", action = "browse", filter = "", page = 1 },
    new { controller = "posts", action = "browse", page = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("NewPost",
    "posts/new",
    new { controller = "", action = "" },
    new { controller = "posts", action = "new" });
```

I thought the constraints I put on them would do the trick, but the requests are all being sent through the first route. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Switch the two routes around...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "NewPost" route needs to be first, as that route would be matched by your "BrowsePosts" route.

Routes are analyzed in order and at the first match that is the route that is utilized.

Map your "NewPost" route first and it should be fixed.

Comment: Haven't had time to play with it (I will tonight) but why is /new matching browse? Shouldn't the constraint stop that?

Comment: @Joe you can think of routes as a stack.  In other words, they are analyzed in order.  ASP.NET will see the route "posts/new" and first attempt to match it up with "posts/{filter}".  It will take that as correct because of the vagueness of the route, and think that "new" should be passed at the route parameter `filter`.  It won't even reach the "NewPost" route due to this.  If you switch them up, though, the "posts/new" route will be matched by "NewPost" route, because that comes first in the route stack.

Comment: ahh...I ALSO had to fill in the defaults. Once I did that it started working. thanks for the tip